# Redirect wordpress site to www from non www on wordpress server

Tags: htaccess

[image]
I am working on a Wordpress project which is deployed on wordpress.com hosting. Simply I want to redirect the website from (with SSL)non-www to (with SSL) www.

I have searched over web and there are plenty of plugins who does the job, but there is a problem with wordpress hosting, it redirects back from www to non-www and resuslts error "too many redirects". I tried to change settings from admin panel settings> General > site url. But its disabled there, I cannot change it. This option is enabled to change on other hosting servers but not on wordpress.com hosting.

I tried it to do that through htaccess but still not working.

if information is not enough I can provide more info.

Kindly help me out with this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately on wordpress.com hosted sites, the www is automatically removed.

For self-hosted wordpress installs, there are several ways to do this.

In `.htaccess` file using something like:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

or set values for WordPress address and Site address in the Wordpress Admin Dashboard:

> Settings > General

or define in your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_HOME',"http://www.example.com");
define('WP_SITEURL',"http://www.example.com");
```

or in your theme `functions.php` file or a plugin.

I think your issue might be one of the above is conflicting with your changes which then causes a redirect loop.

Comment: Hi. I have tried all these options. But none is working on wordpress.com hosting and working fine with other hosting servers. I have edited my question and added a screenshot there. You can see that option to change is disabled on wordpress hosting

Comment: I've amended my answer as on wordpress.com hosted the www is automatically removed. See here under FAQ for clarification: https://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/map-subdomain/